# Why would all Cordova plugins fail to load on iOS?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-ios

I've been asked to make some changes to a (**non-Ionic**) Cordova app previously built by another developer. The project came with a dependency management file, but the previous developer had left Cordova itself out of the dependencies (presumably because he had Cordova globally installed on his machine), so I don't know what version of Cordova he was using. I added the most recent version of Cordova (9.0.0).

The app works great if I run it in the browser through Cordova. However, when I build for iOS and run on my device, it's immediately obvious that some things aren't working correctly, such as the splash screen and keyboard settings.

If I check the console output in Xcode, I see lots of error messages about the plugins right after the application launches. Here are a few examples:

> 2019-04-03 17:24:50.502504-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] ERROR: Plugin BuildInfo' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2019-04-03 17:24:50.502721-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["BuildInfo1245166954","BuildInfo","init",[]]
>
> 2019-04-03 17:24:52.005066-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2019-04-03 17:24:52.005259-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["StatusBar1245166955","StatusBar","_ready",[]]
>
> 2019-04-03 17:24:52.005390-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] ERROR: Plugin 'StatusBar' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in config.xml.
>
> 2019-04-03 17:24:52.005453-0700 APP_NAME[693:225720] -[CDVCommandQueue executePending] [Line 142] FAILED pluginJSON = ["INVALID","StatusBar","hide",[]]

Despite the error messages, the config.xml file already lists the plugins:

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-keyboard" spec="~1.2.0" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" spec="~5.0.2" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" spec="~2.4.2" />
<plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" spec="~7.2.5">
    <variable name="BILLING_KEY" value="[removed]" />
</plugin>
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-buildinfo" spec="^2.0.2" />
```

In `platforms/ios/ios.json`, there is this:

```
"installed_plugins": {
    "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-keyboard": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    },
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {
      "PACKAGE_NAME": "[removed]"
    }
```

In `platforms/ios/www/cordova_plugins.js`, there is this:

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
  {
    "id": "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase.InAppPurchase",
    "file": "plugins/cc.fovea.cordova.purchase/www/store-ios.js",
    "pluginId": "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase",
    "clobbers": [
      "store"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-buildinfo.BuildInfo",
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-buildinfo/www/buildinfo.js",
    "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-buildinfo",
    "clobbers": [
      "BuildInfo"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-keyboard.keyboard",
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-keyboard/www/keyboard.js",
    "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-keyboard",
    "clobbers": [
      "window.Keyboard",
      "cordova.plugins.Keyboard"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen.SplashScreen",
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/www/splashscreen.js",
    "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
    "clobbers": [
      "navigator.splashscreen"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "cordova-plugin-statusbar.statusbar",
    "file": "plugins/cordova-plugin-statusbar/www/statusbar.js",
    "pluginId": "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
    "clobbers": [
      "window.StatusBar"
    ]
  }
];
module.exports.metadata = 
// TOP OF METADATA
{
  "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase": "7.2.8",
  "cordova-plugin-buildinfo": "2.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-keyboard": "1.2.0",
  "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "5.0.2",
  "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "2.4.2",
  "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "1.3.3"
};
// BOTTOM OF METADATA
});
```

In `platforms/ios/www/plugins`, there is a folder for each plugin. Each of those folders contains a `www` folder, within which is a single JS file:

```
platforms/ios/www/plugins
    +---cc.fovea.cordova.purchase
    ¦   +---www
    ¦           store-ios.js
    ¦
    +---cordova-plugin-buildinfo
    ¦   +---www
    ¦           buildinfo.js
    ¦
    +---cordova-plugin-keyboard
    ¦   +---www
    ¦           keyboard.js
    ¦
    +---cordova-plugin-splashscreen
    ¦   +---www
    ¦           splashscreen.js
    ¦
    +---cordova-plugin-statusbar
        +---www
                statusbar.js
```

In Xcode, the .m files for all of the plugins are listed in Build Phases > Compile Sources

I've repeatedly uninstalled and reinstalled the `ios` platform and rebuilt the project, to no avail.

I know that the plugins were working in builds made by the previous developer, and I don't understand why the plugins aren't loading when I make a build; everything seems to be configured correctly.

Comment: It's worth trying to remove the plugins themselves and then add them again.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by downgrading to Cordova 8.1.2